# How to Select * FROM all tables in a schema

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 100s of tables with the same structure in the same schema. I would like to run a query to see all rows where the 'sqft' column is NULL

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE sqft = NULL
```

The tables I would like to iterate over all begin with the prefix 'tb_'
e.g 'tb_115_spooner_st'
After trying numerous solutions posted on here I cannot properly iterate over all these tables with a single script.

This is what I am currently working with

```sql
do $$
declare
    rec record;
    query text;
begin
    for rec in select * from pg_tables where schemaname = 'public'
    loop
        query = format('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE sqft = NULL LIMIT 1', rec.tablename);
        --raise notice '%', query;
        execute query;
    end loop;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I am quite new to writing more complex SQL commands like this and have trouble understanding what is going wrong. I know there needs to be a section where the prefix is a condition, but the code running right now just returns a 'DO' in the console. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the first query change `=` for `IS`, as in `SELECT * FROM table WHERE sqft is NULL
`. Remember, null is not a value.

Comment: Thanks, it still just returns the 'DO' though, how can I get the desired output?

Comment: Why do you have so many very similar tables?

Comment: Each table is for a single apartment building with records containing various information on each unit in the building (sometimes over 400 units)

Comment: Seems like a strange design. I'd consider one, common table for all buildings.

Comment: I agree with jarlh. You should use only a single table. If the total size is really big (hundreds of millions of rows) then maybe think about partitioning by building

Comment: I guess it would be simpler to run queries that way, is there a simple way to consolidate all existing tables into one? Otherwise this would take quite some time

Comment: A DO block can not return anything. You will have to write a (set returning) function

Comment: Horrible schema design and the start of many problems. This simple SELECT statement is just one of them... Advice: Start database normalisation as soon as possible or at least before you got yourself into serious trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view to find the tables you need to query.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', table_name,' WHERE sqft IS NULL;') 
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
  COLUMN_NAME = 'sqft'
```

This will get you a list of SQL statements you can  copy and paste into a new terminal and just run as a normal query.

Comment: I was looking for something to iterate over all tables, but this solves my problem thanks! If I can't find a solution that iterates over the tables I will mark this as the solution.

Comment: Thanks @GustafGyllensporre.  Sorry for over-achieving ;)